# One Logstash instance of cluster fail (many Logstash instances) causes Elasticsearch did not index data

Tags: logstash

I have 3 clusters setup in the production and all 3 clusters are using the common Logstash setup which is setup on 2 machines. However, the disk issue on one of the Elasticsearch cluster is impacting the second Elasticsearch cluster, due to which the data does not get indexed on the second cluster. How can we avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

From what I read i think you are not using separate pipelines causing this behavior, look into using separate pipelines ([Info can be found here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html))
Separating it in different pipelines will make sure it is on a different thread and thus also different queues, do remember that you can have similar filters if required, or even similar inputs.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  The output in the logstash is configured using the if else condition. When a match is found then the logstash will  forward the data  to the respective elasticsearch cluster. Will this configuration not isolate each Elasticsearch cluster from one another so that the disk space issue on cluster not index data on other cluster.

Comment: No it all happens in one pipeline and when the pipeline is full with events which are blocked it cannot handle new ones, so it is better to have separate pipelines for it

Comment: okay. Currently, we have 2 common logstash machine and filebeat is installed on all the machines in the 3 elasticsearch clusters so that output from filebeat is sent to logstash and logstash to elasticsearch. Do we have to use separate logstash machine for all the 3 cluster or using the multi-pipeline configuration would be sufficient to fix the issue currently we are experiencing.

Comment: You can choose which of the two you want to do, both options will solve the issue, splitting to separate logstash machines might be a bit of overkill unless you have spare resources at hand and expect a possible increase of events on them, so they are already separated from the start.

Comment: Thank you @YouryDW. Let me try the multi pipeline configuration

Comment: Hi @YouryDW. Can we use multipipeline logstash configuration for the same beat input? We have filebeat installed on all the servers and the output is sent to logstash_machine:5044. So, three logstash pipeline configurations will use the same port 5044. Will this work?

Comment: No, each pipeline must have it own machine/port. So you will have to check how to detect the difference as soon as possible, if it's based on the machine, change the filebeat on each machine so each machine has it's port. If it based on the file it comes from it'll become harder as you can only define one output in filebeat. If the latter is the case I would suggest looking into the pipeline to pipeline info ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html ), but if a certain pipeline is queue is full up it will still impact the main one where everything comes in.

Answer (score -1):

In your case one solution is to combine multiple pipelines with the pipeline-to-pipeline communication.

Since you have 3 elasticsearch clusters, you will need 4 pipelines, one to receive your data and the other 3 to output to each elasticsearch cluster.

In the input pipeline you will have something like this:

```
input {
  your input
}
filter {
  your filters
}
output {
  pipeline {
    send_to => [es1, es2, es3]
  }
}
```

Then for every cluster you will need a pipeline configuration like this one:

```
input {
  pipeline {
    address => es1
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    output for your es1 cluster
  }
}
```

This is the [output isolator pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#output-isolator-pattern) and it is used to prevent that one output in your logstash pipeline blocks the other ones if it fails, which is your case.

To use [multiple pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html) you need to configure your `pipelines.yml` like this example:

```
- pipeline.id: your-input-pipeline
  path.config: "/path/to/the/config/input.conf"

- pipeline.id: your-cluster1-pipeline
  path.config: "/path/to/the/config/cluster1.conf"

- pipeline.id: your-cluster2-pipeline
  path.config: "/path/to/the/config/cluster2.conf"

- pipeline.id: your-cluster3-pipeline
  path.config: "/path/to/the/config/cluster3.conf"
```

Comment: When I read 'If any of the persistent queues of the downstream pipelines (in the example above, buffered-es and buffered-http) become full, both outputs will stop.' It will not solve the issue that user11549576 has?

Comment: Without more information about the OP there is no way to be sure. If persisted queue is being used, it could block. This configuration allows to keep sending data in case of a temporary failure of one of the outputs, of course if the failure persists it would stop sometime, Logstash alone can not solve that.